# AngularJS doesn't refresh the page after rerouting

Tags: angularjs

I have

```
mainApp.config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
    .when('view1', {
        controller: 'SimpleController',
        templateUrl: 'views/page.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/views/page.html'});
});
```

which works, when I go in the browser to my main page

```
http://localhost:8080/web/main.html
```

it does change the URL immediately to

```
http://localhost:8080/web/views/page.html
```

but without actually refreshing the page so I still see the old content from main.html instead

Did I miss a step?

Comment: that's the whole principle behind routers: you don't get to "f5" refresh the whole page all over again. so angular is doing the right thing what you told it to do.

Comment: but I don't see the content of the second page ...

Comment: .when gets the relative URL path as an argument. this is why you are automatically redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

You are just redirecting to, you shouldn't be seeing any `.html`,

You need to start from a root if you plan on doing `SPA` type routing:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  }).
  .otherwise({
     redirectTo: '/'
  });
```